# How to play one audio channel in both speakers?

Tags: windows, audio

I've encountered some games which only play audio on the left or right channel; this becomes irritating quickly *especially* when wearing headphones and proprietary games of course can't be easily modified, unlikely multimedia files.

Windows' volume mixer options are sparse and there doesn't seem to be an option in sound settings either.

Comment: I haven’t looked recently but there once was a mono checkbox in the audio mixer.

Comment: @Tyson: Which version of Windows?

Comment: I thought 7 but looked and it’s not there and I’m not sure anymore. , I just booted several old images looking, maybe that was something a driver added in like xp era... guess I shouldn’t have even commented.  I do remember a check box I used tho to get audio out of box speakers for 1 game

Comment: I've never come across anything in recent times that wasn't mixed for 5.1 let alone stereo - are you certain you don't have your sound manager set to 5.1 rather than stereo, & that you're in the correct socket, with a properly matching plug?

Comment: @Tetsujin: Practically yes because to issues are limited to extremely specific titles with known issues. [Platypus II](http://store.steampowered.com/app/319180/Platypus_II/) (2007) is such game, feel free to test ($1.39/1,19€/£0.99 during sale).

Comment: ah, so not exactly 'recent times' then. I don't really feel the need to buy something to test, sorry.